# i'm trying to create a phonebook using bash script and i would like to ask how to delete only one contact from this phonebook?

Tags: bash, scripts

Here is my code but when I run it it deletes all the contacts that begin with the variable name (`name_delete`).

```
read -p "please enter the contact name you want to delete:" name_delete
sed -i /$name_delete/d database 
echo "the contact is deleted" ;;
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel if there are excellent tools available, e.g. [khard](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/khard) and [ppl](https://github.com/hensmith/ppl)? Or is this merely a training task, not really about a phonebook and your question actually is how to match a full line with sed? If the latter, `sed -i /^$name_delete$/d database` should do the trick. In any case, please [edit] and clarify!

Comment: If I’m right about what you’re question actually is, please [edit] and add example lines from `database`, especially those which are getting deleted.

Comment: Hmmm. This reads like a homework problem.

Comment: @user535733 Those are not off-topic per se, and OP clearly made efforts to solve the task on their own, showed what they got and mentioned a precise problem.

Comment: @dessert, agreed.

Comment: How do you know what contact to delete, if your pattern matches multiple contacts? You'll need a better search, or you want to show them all & pick one - is that the question, how to pick one from a list?